# Static Website Flet deployment - No module error

Tags: web, deployment, modulenotfounderror, flet

I can run my Flet application in the IDE and it renders in a browser, everything works.

However, once built as a static website it produces the /dist folder as expected. I have created a local website in IIS (on the same machine) and pointed at this folder.

When I post the url it tries to start my application but is does not load. F12 to view developer options shows the error ...

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

The module is installed.

Am I missing a path? Version of py is 3.7.2

I have tried to set paths but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `requirements.txt` before running `flet publish`? If not, then try to add your custom dependencies in that file before running. That will solve your issue.

And one more thing, if your app does some heavy work, static website is not a better option. Static website made in flet takes huge time to load.

Hope it helps!